# Angular: Rest Query based on Result of Previous Query

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following panel that populates just the header panel (with Titles) based on a REST call. 
  How do I populate the DIV tag below () in the body section  based on the ID found in the panel's  header? I am not sure how Angular would do this.

```
<accordion id="0022" close-others="false">
                    <accordion-group isopen="opened" is-open="opened">
                        <accordion-heading>
                            {{m.PLabel}} <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': opened, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !opened}"></i>
                        </accordion-heading>
                        <div class="label-primary">
                            <h2>**How do I get data here based on different REST** call?</h2>
                        </div>


                    </accordion-group>
                </accordion>
```

An example would be ---> select data.* from data where ID=accordionid(0022)
The accordionid would come form the header Id above (e.g.0022)

Comment: seem to be working backwards, should be working from controller and then to view. WHat is `m` in controller scope?

Comment: Yes you want to be in your controller using the promises that are built into $http where you nest the next $http.get inside of the promise function or success function of the previous call

Comment: Are you only trying to populate the div panels below the accordian header's when they are expanded?

Comment: I want to populate both the header and the panel body on load at the same time but the panel body needs to populate data related to the header's ID. If it were sql the body would be select * from bodytable bt where bt.id=header.id

Comment: And you can't load them both at the same time because they're from different http sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply talking about a delayed $http call using the header's id, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BJ5Wj/) might demonstrate a method for doing so.  Basically, you would bind to the results of your inital $http call for the headers, and then make a subsequent $http call when the user clicks on the header by referencing the id that the header is bound to in the ng-click of the header.

```
<div ng-repeat="header in headers" ng-click="getPanelContents(header.id)">{{header.name}}</div>
```

And in your controller add a $scope variable that is a function call that you pass the id to

```
$scope.getPanelContents = function(headerId){
    var results = $http('resource/' + headerId);        
};
```

Comment: Sonicblis, I do not need to click a button. Maybe there is a loading event for the accordion-group or accordion-toggle element that I need to trigger and pass a value. Does anyone know if this is the case? I will have to research.